# Traversing a hyperplane

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, discrete-geometry

I am trying to implement (using Matlab) the traversal of 
$$\left\{\left(k_1,..., k_N\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\in\mathbb{N}_0^N: \sum_{i=1}^N k_i=c\right\}$$
where $c\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is a prescribed constant. Is there an easy recursive or even explicit way to do this?

Comment: By traversal, you mean a continuous path through the different $n$-tuples with integer coordinates summing up to $n$ ?

Comment: Only visiting every point once would be enough. I think one can use a recursive algorithm by fixing one coordinate, say the last one, and solve a corresponding problem $\mathbb{N}_{0}^{N-1}$. But, maybe there are more efficient ways?